# Processing a circular rainbow in an image

Tags: image-processing

While on a cross-country flight, I observed what looked like a complete circular rainbow, visible against the backdrop of clouds. I took several photos thru the window with my small Nikon camera, one of which is shown below:

[image]

We were at about 35,000 feet with a complete cloud deck below us. I looked down and saw this rainbow-like structure above the clouds.  It remained in view for about 10 minutes, and it went away when the cloud deck began to rise with respect to our flight path.

While in flight my eyes had no trouble discerning the shape and colors Red, Orange, Yellow, Green, and Blue, but no Indigo or Violet. However, when I uploaded the photos to my desktop I could barely make out these colors.

I've been trying to use Mathematica to bring out the rainbow in the images, but without much success.  I'm asking for ideas on how to enhance the colors and structure of the rainbow.  As you will note in the photo, there appears to be further structure outside the main rainbow, so it would be interesting to manipulate multiple parameters in the photo.

Comment: Just to be nitpicking ;-), I believe that's a "glory".

Comment: FYI: why you didn't see "violet" as it is meant today: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9udYi7exojk

Comment: I wonder why your camera failed to capture any significant color, at least as presented in this image.  I don't suppose there is a "RAW" (digital negative) file?  Out of curiosity was a polarizing filter of any kind in use?

Comment: This is a slightly different phenomenon from a rainbow. It is called a "Brocken Spectre".

Comment: @Mr.Wizard  I guess the eye copes better with the very bright conditions (higher dynamic range) . A polarizing filter per se should not be a problem (perhaps in combination with the windows). I had  similar (mediocre) results last time I captured a glory.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Probably not since the date is imprinted on the image.  But that would be the way to go indeed.

Comment: This is not a rainbow--due to refraction (bending) of light and dispersion (different bending for different wavelengths)--but instead a halo, due to diffraction of light off of very small water particles. The colors are always less saturated (less intense) than in a rainbow, and the angular size and colors depend upon the size of the particles. A rainbow always subtends an angle of 42 degrees from the anti-solar point (the point opposite the sun), whereas halos are almost always of smaller angular size and (as mentioned) the size depends upon the droplet size.

Answer (score 12):

Another approach is to try and histogram equalize the image to something similar, but with more pronounced colors. I found this picture at google images

```
img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/ogkEu.jpg"];
img2=Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/vEkvx.jpg"];
```

[image]

Then the desired picture can take on (something of) the coloration of the new image using

```
HistogramTransform[img, img2]
```

[image]

Comment: I wonder why there is so much white in there

Comment: @belisarius -- it's hard to know for sure, but I would guess it is a result of the transformation working on a channel-by-channel basis.

Comment: curious,isn't it? `{h, s, b} = ColorSeparate[img, "HSB"];
{h2, s2, b2} = ColorSeparate[img2, "HSB"]; ColorCombine[{HistogramTransform[h, h2],   HistogramTransform@s, HistogramTransform@b}, "HSB"]`

Comment: @belisarius -- The weird colors actually make some sense:  the hue channel is getting all scrambled around by the equalization, essentially returning random colors. For comparison, try `HistogramTransform[ColorConvert[img, "LAB"], ColorConvert[img2, "LAB"]]`

Comment: Is this answer really *enhancing* the colours and structure that exist in the original image, or is it simply imposing the colours and structure of a different image on it?

Comment: @Rahul - histogram equalization recolors the image to have a similar spectrum as the model -- that is why I picked  `img2` to have the colors similar to those the OP said were really there. Certainly, if a more accurate `img2` could be found, it would give results closer to the original scene.

Answer (score 12):

Plain old `ImageAdjust` will improve it quite a lot, though you have to chop off the bright orange text to stop the algorithm being fooled:

```
ImageAdjust[img ~ImageTake~ 2100]
```

[image]

You could now bring out the colours a bit more with a boost to the contrast of the saturation channel:

```
 ColorCombine[MapAt[ImageAdjust[#, {0, 2, 1}] &, ColorSeparate[%, "HSB"], 2], "HSB"]
```

[image]

Answer (score 10):

There appears to be insufficient data in the provided image.  Boosting saturation by a factor of ten:

```
img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/ogkEu.jpg"];

hsb = ColorConvert[img, "HSB"];

ImageApply[# {1, 10, 1} &, hsb]
```

[image]

Comment: @MichaelE2 Oops!  I used a drag-and-drop in the code I actually ran and that produced an alpha channel, then I just added the `Import` when I pasted it here.  It was hubris to think I knew how the code would evaluate.